# What video game are these ninjas in Pixels from?

Tags: game-identification

As asked by JoshDM on [Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/37079/what-video-game-are-the-ninjas-from):

> In the movie ***Pixels***, Josh Gad's character battles several chibi-style ninjas that are assaulting a school bus.  I do not recognize what video game these ninjas are from.
>
> [image: screencap of a ninja from the trailer]
>
> In the film, all the games that appear are from the 80's.
>
> What game are they from, or are they from a fictional game like the "Lady Lisa" character, or were they sourced from 1980's pop culture, like the Smurf must have been?

Comment: It looks like "I-Ninja" but the outfit is not the same and I-Ninja came out in 2003.

Comment: I encouraged T&a to replicate the question here as I had no access to do so myself at the time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The ninjas are from a fake 80's videogame created for the movie, called Dojo Quest:

[Here's an article](http://www.fayobserver.com/living/weekender/bit-icons-a-look-at-the-video-games-of-pixels/article_de31688c-c066-53c5-aa1b-7a3f7f1a230c.html) about the licensed games in the movie:

> The filmmakers licensed characters from real-world video games for the movie, but they opted to craft a fictional title starring a ninja-fighting heroine named Lady Lisa (played by Ashley Benson), who serves as an unconventional love interest for Gad's character.  To promote "Pixels," Sony released a side-scrolling mobile game resembling "Dojo Quest."
>
> "Lady Lisa was in the first draft of the script, and I thought it would be fun to create just one game that didn't exist back in the '80s," said Columbus. "It never occurred to me not to do it. I felt like we could get away with it. A character like Lara Croft could've worked, but I loved the fact that Josh Gad's character has been pining for this woman all his life."

Comment: Oh so that's the deal with Lady Lisa, I though she was from a real game. I'll proceed to delete my wrong answer then.

Comment: The problem here, from a film standpoint (beyond all the other glaring problems) is that while Lady Lisa was shown (briefly) in the 80's, her ninja antagonists were nowhere to be seen in the film till their appearance in the final battle.

Comment: " I loved the fact that Josh Gad's character has been pining for this woman all his life." ... I just don't have the words for it. Egad.